# Datagrab import, P&T dropdown not registering

Tags: supersearch, datagrab, field-pack, csv

I'm importing a CSV of around 60 dogs using Datagrab.

The import works fine but when I use Solspace Super Search, it seems to be ignoring the gender of the dog (a P&T dropdown field).

If I resave the entry, it's fine, search works great.

I can't fathom whether this is a Super Search issue or a Datagrab issue. When I look at the field in the db after import, the value is definitely there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try rebuilding the Super Search Lexicon? (go to: SuperSearch > Utilities).

I have a feeling that Super Search only updates this if you add the entries through the Control Panel.

Comment: yeah I tried that but the same thing remains